# SAS Maintaining last non null character variable until it changes

Tags: sas

In the 3rd and fourth observation the value for status is null, i need the 3rd and 4th observation to equal the second ob.  this needs to occur thru the data set by id.

```
data z;
 input  id $ d status $;
 cards;
11111 01 a
11111 02 a
11111 03 .
11111 04 . 
11111 05 p
11111 06 . 
11111 07 . 
11111 08 . 
11111 09 a
11111 10 . 
11111 11 . 
11111 12 . 
11111 13 . 
11111 14 . 
11111 15 . 
11111 16 . 
11112 01 p
11112 02 . 
11112 03 . 
11112 04 . 
11112 05 p
11112 06 . 
11112 07 . 
11112 08 . 
11112 09 . 
11112 10 a
;
run;
```

Comment: It's not completely clear what is the desired result. Do you want only exactly 3rd and 4th observation for each id to make equal with 2nd one? Then how to deal with id=11112? The 2nd row for it is empty as well. Or you want to make all empty values equal to the nearest previous non-empty one (within one id)?

Comment: Laurent's response below is spot on.  Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

This data step should do the trick.

```
data want;
 set z;
 by id;
 length lastStatus $1;
 retain lastStatus;
 if first.id then lastStatus = status;
 else lastStatus = coalescec(status,lastStatus);
 drop status;
 rename lastStatus = status;
run;
```